# I keep getting 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is for an edhesive class, and it works fine when I use Eclipse Compiler. But for some reason when I enter it into the edhesive's compiler, the error keeps popping up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What month were you born in? (number)");
        int month = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What day? (number)");
        int day = scan.nextInt();

        String[] arrayM = {
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        };
        String[] arrayD = {
                "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eight", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelvth", "thirteenth",
                "fourteenth", "fifteenth", "sixteenth", "seventeenth", "eighteenth", "nineteenth", "twentieth", "twenty-first",
                "twenty-second", "twenty-third", "twenty-fourth", "twenty-fifth", "twenty-sixth", "twenty-seventh",
                "twenty-ninth", "thirtieth", "thirty-first"
        };

        System.out.println("Your birthday is: " + arrayM[month - 1] + " " + arrayD[day - 1]);

        if (month == 1) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 19)
                System.out.println("Capricorn");
            else if (day >= 20 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Aquarius");
        } else if (month == 2) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 18)
                System.out.println("Aquarius");
            else if (day >= 19 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Pisces");
        } else if (month == 3) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 20)
                System.out.println("Pisces");
            else if (day >= 21 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Aries");
        } else if (month == 4) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 21)
                System.out.println("Aries");
            else if (day >= 22 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Taurus");
        } else if (month == 5) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 20)
                System.out.println("Taurus");
            else if (day >= 21 && day <= 31) ;
            System.out.println("Gemini");
        } else if (month == 6) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 20)
                System.out.println("Gemini");
            else if (day >= 21 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Cancer");
        } else if (month == 7) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 22)
                System.out.println("Gemini");
            else if (day >= 23 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Leo");
        } else if (month == 8) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 22)
                System.out.println("Leo");
            else if (day >= 23 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Virgo");
        } else if (month == 9) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 22)
                System.out.println("Virgo");
            else if (day >= 1 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Libra");
        } else if (month == 10) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 22)
                System.out.println("Libra");
            else if (day >= 23 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Scorpio");
        } else if (month == 11) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 21)
                System.out.println("Scorpio");
            else if (day <= 22 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Sagittarius");
        } else if (month == 12) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 21)
                System.out.println("Sagittarius");
            else if (day >= 22 && day <= 31)
                System.out.println("Capricorn");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this using a debugger and stepping through to see why you are going out of bounds?

Comment: edhesive's compiler? is it just compiling java program?

Comment: I'm kinda new here so I don't really know how to use a debugger or if its the same thing as a compiler. As for edhesive's compiler, the compilers I use (eclipse and JDK) don't turn up with that error. So I don't know if it's the code or edhesive's thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "twenty-eighth" is missing in the arrayD, so there are only 30 elements.

Comment: Btw. "May" seems to be missing from the arrayM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, even after I fixed it, I got another one of those errors, except now instead of 30 it says 12.

Comment: Did you fix the missing "May" too in the arrayM?